# IE 9 set cookie and redirect fails

Tags: java, spring, internet-explorer, cookies, redirect

In my spring-application I try to set a cookie and than redirect to a page where the cookie is read. The redirect to another webpage works, but setting the cookies fails only in IE9.

```
Cookie cookie = MyCookieHandler.createCookie(parameters, domain);
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

The redirect is handled buy setting the ModelAndView

```
modelView = new ModelAndView("redirect:" + getCallback());
```

As I said works fine in FF3+, Chrome and IE7/IE8. What wrong in my app? Any suggestions?

Comment: Capture your 302's HTTP response headers using Fiddler and post them here.

Comment: and what does your createCookie method do?

Comment: `HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Wed, 27 Jul 2011 09:27:12 GMT
Location: /login/index.html
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15
X-Cache: MISS from ham-dmz-mns1.mobilcom.de
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from ham-dmz-mns1.myserver.de:8080
Via: 1.0 ham-dmz-mns1.myserver.de:8080 (squid/2.7.STABLE5)
Connection: keep-alive
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive`

Comment: but it's not the redirect whicht fails, it's setting the cookie. On Domain xxx.google.com we set the cookie for google.com and on yyy.google.com the cookie isn't available. It's crazy because in FF, Chrome etc. it works fine, only IE9 fails...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some tries I added the following:

```
response.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

Now it works for me, don't know if this is the right solution and don't know why the caching is different in IE9 but now it works... thanks guys.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issues with IE 8, 9, and 10 and the cache control headers did not help. After further research, I had to put a [P3P privacy policy](http://www.w3.org/TR/P3P/) (from an older Java web app) in place and IE stored the cookie properly without the cache control headers.

This policy format is only honored by Internet Explorer these days, but provides the only reliable means of managing cookies without manual changes in the IE privacy settings. There are two parts to a P3P privacy policy: policy file and compact policy header. The compact policy header seems to work well enough. The different categories of P3P have compact codes for brevity in the header, e.g. navigation => NAV. At a minimum, I would start with INT, NAV, and UNI codes for the compact policy.

Here are two examples of how to pass back the header:

```
Grails/Java:
    response.setHeader("P3P", "CP='INT NAV UNI'");

PHP:
    header('P3P:CP="INT NAV UNI"')
```

Comment: Confirming. This specific P3P header solved "cookie not set on POST redirect" issue with IE11 (Edge) for me. Nothing else was changed. When this method starts to fail, fall back to META tag-based refresh / redirect:  http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/redirect-meta-refresh.phtml

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem of failed redirection before. It strangely seemed to work in Firefox, but failed in IE. The solution was to add a full URL to the redirect statement, i.e.

```
http://foo.com/new_site.html
```

instead of

```
new_site.html
```

Comment: Try adding http:// in front of it then. This seems to be an IE security settings issue.

Comment: oh sorry, it was `http://yyy.google.com` (was ignored by the commentbox) and even if the callback is set without http(s) my app add this.